# VIM how to substitute with offset

Tags: vim, offset, substitution

The search command in vim allows you to place the cursor relative to the search results. For example, `/hello/b+2` places the cursor on the first `l`.

How do I do that with the substitute command?

```
s/hello/b+2/_/
```

does not work.

I need this to replace not the entire search string, but a portion of it only (specifically, to blank out all but the first character of a word).

Comment: Please elaborate. Didn't get your requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You generally have two options: similar to other regex engines zero-width matches (though with different syntax):

```
:s/\(he\)\@<=llo/_/
```

or vim-specific “set the start of the match here”:

```
:s/he\zsllo/_/
```

. Also, there is a workaround which will look similar in almost every other regex engine:

```
:s/\(he\)llo/\1_/
```

: this captures text that should be unchanged and makes replacement include it.